# Text recognition with Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia, text-recognition

I am struggling to use text recognition. When I try it, it return this error,

```
"An assembly with the same name `Vuforia.UnityExtensions' has already been imported. Consider removing one of the references or sign the assembly
/Applications/Unity/PlaybackEngines/VuforiaSupport/Managed/Runtime/Vuforia.UnityExtensions.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)
Assets/Vuforia/Scripts/Internal/Vuforia.UnityExtensions.dll (Location of the symbol related to previous error)"
```

[image]

And it does not show a Text Reco behavior (script) even if I click text recognition.
What is happening ? To use text recognition, I am using Unity version 2.0f3 and imported vuforia-unity-6-2-10.unitypackage.
It would be really appreciated if it is explained in detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **Unity** 2017 or later you do not need to Import a **Vuforia** package manually. To use the **Vuforia** SDK you simply need to enable it in the `Player settings` in **Unity**. If the option is not visible in **Unity**, you need to download it first by clicking on the link in **Unity**[image: Vuforia]

You will then be able to use **Vuforia's** features.
Don't forget to remove all **Vuforia** related files before you install the package via **Unity's** downloader.

Comment: Keep in mind that text recognition has been removed in Vuforia 7

Comment: @dave Quote from Vuforia's forum: *Keep in mind, the natively integrated Vuforia 6.5 that comes with Unity 2017.2 still has the Text Recognition feature. The premade objects are unavailable, but you can still set the feature up by adding the necessary scripts to an object.*